# Decimal 2 in calculated field

Tags: sql, count, decimal, calculated-columns

Sorry but I'not able to obtain a result as 2 decimals for the column "%".

Can anyone help me?

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    "column1"
    COUNT("column1"),
    COUNT("column1") * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "table") AS "%",
    AVG( "column2" )
FROM 
    "table"
GROUP BY 
    "column1"
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Typo, missing comma after first select item.

Comment: Help use help you - please share some sample data, the result you're getting with this query and the result you'd want to get. Also, tagging the question with the right [tag:rdbms] would help.

Answer (score 1):

Some databases do integer division, and `count()` returns an integer.  You should convert to a decimal point representation.  I think the simplest way is to multiply by 1.0.  Also, you don't need the subquery; you can use window functions:

```
SELECT "column1", COUNT( "column1" ),
       COUNT("column1") * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percent
       AVG("column2") 
ROM "table"
GROUP BY "column1";
```

To get two decimals, convert to the decimal type (or a string, but the former is standard):

```
SELECT "column1", COUNT("column1"),
       CAST(COUNT("column1") * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as DECIMAL(5, 2)) as percent
       AVG("column2") 
FROM "table"
GROUP BY "column1";
```

Also note that the `AVG()` is subject to the same rules as integer division.  If you want a value with decimal places, multiply by 1.0 (or do an explicit conversion).